# External database content

Tags: wordpress

I have a database which contains categories and articles.

I want to transfert all this content to a new wordpress website.

Is there a way to import data into a wordpress website ?

I want to do that by code because i will need to run import several times.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

WordPress supports exporting and importing data. Check out the "Tools" menu.